# Author Footnote Indentation

Tags: footnotes, margins, indentation, footmisc

How do you set the footnote margin for footnotes included in `\title`, `\author`, or `\date`?

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage[hang, flushmargin]{footmisc}
    \title{Title}
    \author{Author\footnote{Indentation is incorrect.}}
    \setlength{\footnotemargin}{15pt}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

Hello world.\footnote{Indentation is correct.}
    
\end{document}
```

In the above example, `\setlength{\footnotemargin}{15pt}` only changes the indentation of the footnotes in the body of the document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\maketitle` as defined by the `article` class redefines `\@makefntext`. This means that inside `\maketitle` `footmisc`'s definition of `\@makefntext` is forgotten…

You can patch `\maketitle` and change the definition back again:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[hang, flushmargin]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{15pt}

\title{Title}
\author{Author\thanks{Indentation is incorrect.}}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\let\fm@makefntext\@makefntext
\patchcmd\maketitle{\if@twocolumn}{\let\@makefntext\fm@makefntext\if@twocolumn}{}{\fail}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle

Hello world.\footnote{Indentation is correct.}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, that explains what was going wrong! Excellent, +1.

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but I also don't know what you mean when you say "Indentation is (in)correct". Please show what you are expecting for "correct indentation" in the two cases.

I have a feeling that footnotes, normally specified via `\thanks` in the `\title`, and `\author` and `\date` arguments is not coded quite the same as normal footnotes (in which case the `footmisc` package might not apply).

Someone please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I tried to change the margin with ``\setlength{\footnotemargin}{15pt}``, and that did not change the margin for the footnote after ``\author``. This is what I mean by "indentation is incorrect".